# Active Directory Delegated Permissions grant multiple users access to edit a Global Security group with powershell

Tags: active-directory, permissions, powershell, delegation

Hello Fellow IT Guru’s

I am hoping to gain a little knowledge here regarding the ability to manage Active Directory Delegated permissions through powershell.

I’ve recently ran into an issue where I wanted to provide multiple users the ability to add or remove users into a Global Security Group.

I am familiar with the tedious way of adding multiple users via AD:

```
1. security tab, add, enter users name, uncheck all permissions for said user
2. click advanced tab, double click users name, ensure type is set to “Allow” and applies to is set to “this object only” 
3. scroll through the entire list of permissions, and ensure only “write members” has a tick mark
4. ok, ok.
```

I’ve researched the Internet regarding this topic and I have only come across cmdlets for providing multiple users the ability to manage Distribution List’s
    1. Set-DistributionGroup -Identity '' -ManagedBy  'user1', 'user2','user3

While this command is helpful, it is not what I am looking for. 
I’ve also tested the following command to no avail

```
1. Set-Group -Identity '<DL_name>' -ManagedBy  'user1', 'user2'
```

I am new to powershell, and I have read and researched, so if I am on the complete wrong track please just let me know.

Much Appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Fair warning. Modifying Windows permissions programmatically (on anything) has a pretty steep learning curve if you're not familiar with how Windows permissions work.

The Powershell cmdlets you'll be dealing with are [`Get-Acl`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-acl?view=powershell-5.1) and [`Set-Acl`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-acl?view=powershell-5.1) combined with the .NET class [`System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectoryaccessrule(v=vs.110).aspx).

The high level overview to modify the permissions on an object look something like this:

- `Get-Acl` to retrieve the current permissions on the object
- Create new `ActiveDirectoryAccessRule` objects for the ACEs you will be adding
- use the `AddAccessRule` method on the ACL object previously retrieved
- `Set-Acl` with your modified ACL object.

This should get you started on the right path.

Per Corey's comment, here's a nice blog post that ties it all together with some examples:
[Active Directory Delegation via PowerShell](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/joec/2013/04/25/active-directory-delegation-via-powershell/)

Comment: This a good reference along the lines above. Feel free if you want to add it to the answer.
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/joec/2013/04/25/active-directory-delegation-via-powershell/

Answer (score 0):

Just adding that the technet blog linked in the original answer is no longer available at that URL, the current URL is here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/joec/active-directory-delegation-via-powershell

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/573252)